# Django CharField as primary key still allow Null value to be save

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

Currently i have the following model that i would like to set CharField as primary key( my database is Mysql)

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = "customers"
        verbose_name = _('Customer')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Customers')

    customer_id = models.CharField(_('Customer ID'),max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

In the [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#primary-key) it stated that :

> primary_key=True implies null=False and unique=True. Only one primary
> key is allowed on an object.

In Mysql the primary key has the following structure:

> customer_id, type=varchar(255), collation=latin1_swedish_ci,
> Attributes=blank Null=No, Default=None,Comments=blank, Extra=blank

but when i try to use the save() method with null value for primary key:

```
Customer.objects.create(customer_id=None, name="abc")
```

It still save Null value in the primary key without returning any error or validation, why is that?

**EDIT:**
After saving in Mysql it show the value of the customer_id=blank(when try to save it as None). Why it set to blank when saving customer_id=None?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create object for the first time

```
Customer.objects.create(customer_id=None, name="abc")
```

It will store `customer_id` value as '' (empty value, not null) and there are no other object we have created till now, so it's unique too.

Now when you again create an Customer object

```
Customer.objects.create(customer_id=None, name="xyz")
```

This will throw an error `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: customers.customer_id` because we already have empty value in our `customer_id` value. So, this is throwing an error of UNIQUE constraint

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Django Rest Framework?

Then you may have add your **customer_id** to the **read_only_fields** in **serializer.py**

**The result is:**

- You can't add an id in your request
- Django doesn't recognised it as a required field anymore (except of Django Admin)
- Django accepts a NULL value, which shouldn't be allowed